# How do I pass props and other parameters to function using React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How do I pass props and other parameters to function using React Hooks?

I have the following function:

```
async function handleSubmit(props, event) {
    const {history} = props;
    if (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
    ...
}
```

How can a call it from a `<Form>` and populate the `props` and `event` parameters?

`<Form inline onSubmit={handleSubmit}>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring this out.  You just need to add the `props` parameter to the component function definition, see below:

```
const Header = props => {

    const handleSubmit = async event => {
        const {history} = props;
        if (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
        ...
    };

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try writing it like this

```
 const handleSubmit = async props => event => {
    const {history} = props;
    if (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
    ...
}
```

And then

```
<Form inline onSubmit={handleSubmit(props)}
```

Look into currying in javascript :)

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  This is almost working but the second function isn't an async function.  Moving `async` to right before `event` didn't work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new arrow function onClick, and pass the props to it as a second parameter (or first if you want).

```
<Form inline onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e, props)}>
```

Comment: When I use this, I get a "`props` is not defined" error